# mod_proxy redirect with ajp connector

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, proxy, ajp

So i am trying to use the mod_proxy module to redirect traffic coming from 192.168.2.0 to go to www.google.com. and 192.168.5.10 to go to www.hotmail.com as an example. Getting confused on using the Rewrite engine! Any help would be great, thanks. Using the ajp connecter from apache to tomcat.

Redirect permanent 192.168.2.0 http://www.google.com

```
#Deny from All
Order deny,allow
Allow from 192.168.5.0

RewriteEngine On
```

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192.168.16.210$
RewriteRule /foo(.*)$ http://www.google.com$1 [P,L]